# Best starting point for multiple selection in file/folder tree structure wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm looking to create a window with two panels, with a collapsible folder browser in the left panel and a list of files in the right panel that are contained in the selected folder on the left (similar to nautilus or an older windows explorer). Both the folders on the left and files on the right need a check box beside them so users can make a selection of a mix of folders and files across their whole file system.

I've had a look around and found similar-ish built-in bits in wx like `GenericDirCtrl` but before I get started I wanted to ask if anyone had come across something like this before that's available or if there was a better starting point that `GenericDirCtrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it all working now. I used `CustomTreeCtrl` for the tree and a list control that has multi inheritance from `ListCtrl` and `CheckListCtrlMixin` for the report like list with check boxes.
I can share the code if anyone's interested

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in file explorer. The GenericDirCtrl or one of the other tree controls is a good place to start for the tree. Then use a ListCtrl (or ObjectListView) for the other panel. Something like that should give you the functionality you need.